# import-csv? Parse custom header with metadata in powershell ISE

Tags: powershell, csv

Forgive me if this is a silly question, I am new to powershell.  So I have a vendor sending flat files to my data collection system that are named by the serial number of the part.  I have multiple machines sending files that are all hitting a central computer for data concentration.  My manager setup powershell scripts to map drives on our share drive and move those files to folders on the shared drive.  I want to separate those files in that powershell script to folders for each machine.  The flat file looks something like this:

```
 Premachine ID:     
 Main Machine name ID: ,ABCD1234Z    
 More stuff: ,Stuff    
 Date: ,02/02/22    
 Time: ,5:55:55 am
 Filename: ,c:\exportfolder\SN_GOBBLY_GOOK_2_02_2022.CSV

 Events:

 Alarms:

 Header1, Header2, Header3, Header4, Header5, Etc    
 1,2,3,4,5,6    
 1,2,3,4,5,6
```

I just want to move the file to a folder based off of the Main ID,  ABCD1234Z.

I thought to use something like

```
$press = Import-Csv Share:\folder\SN_GOBBLY_GOOK_2_02_2022.CSV -Delimiter "," | select -ExpandProperty Main Machine name ID:
```

and

```
$press = Import-Csv Share:\folder\SN_GOBBLY_GOOK_2_02_2022.CSV -Delimiter ":" | select -ExpandProperty Main Machine name ID
```

If I can get the data into the variable, I can take it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all those files are consistently formatted like that, then you could do something in a few lines, like so:

```
$lines = (Get-Content ./test.csv) -Split "`n" 
$line = $lines | Select-String -Pattern "Main Machine name ID:"
$partNumber = $line.ToString().Split(",")[1]
```

`$partNumber` then is ABCD1234Z

You could reduce that down to 2 lines of course, but readability and all.

Answer (score 0):

If this is always line 2 (index 1 in an array), this can be done in one line.

```
# mock file data
$data = @'
Premachine ID:     
 Main Machine name ID: ,ABCD1234Z    
 More stuff: ,Stuff    
 Date: ,02/02/22    
 Time: ,5:55:55 am
 Filename: ,c:\exportfolder\SN_GOBBLY_GOOK_2_02_2022.CSV

 Events:

 Alarms:

 Header1, Header2, Header3, Header4, Header5, Etc    
 1,2,3,4,5,6    
 1,2,3,4,5,6
'@

# testing, save to a temp file
$data | Out-File -FilePath (Join-Path $env:TEMP 'so_test.txt')


#
# as a one-liner
#

$name = ((Get-Content (Join-Path $env:TEMP 'so_test.txt'))[1] -split ',')[1].Trim()

Write-Output "Found name: '$name'."
```

The steps involved.

1. Get-Content returns all lines in an array.
2. Index 1 is 2nd line.
3. split on comma to get the parts
4. get 2nd part, index 1
5. Trim extraneous spaces

There's your name.

Answer (score 0):

This approach uses Regular Expression to get the ID you are after:

```
# read the data from the flat file in one single string using the '-Raw' switch
$data = Get-Content -Path 'PATH TO THE FLAT FILE' -Raw

$machineID = ([regex]'Main Machine.*ID:\s*,?(\w+)').Match($data).Groups[1].Value
```

After this, `$machineID` holds the ID like in this example `ABCD1234Z` or is an empty string if the flat file did not contain a line 'Main Machine ...'

**Regex Details**

```
Main Machine  Match the characters “Main Machine” literally
.             Match any single character that is not a line break character
   *          Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
ID:           Match the characters “ID:” literally
\s            Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
   *          Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
,             Match the character “,” literally
(             Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   \w         Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, etc.)
      +       Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
```